# New GPU not recognized by OpenCL and crashes often in simple render and shader mode in viewport, help?

Tags: rendering, gpu

GPU is 4070ti and only other updated component was my PSU for a higher wattage level. Previously was using a 2080ti that never had these issues.

When using blender version 2.93 (tried 3.0 as well and 2.79 but most of what I could find online mentioned OpenGL not being supported for these so I figured maybe that was the problem) now that I have a new gpu, suddenly it crashes every few minutes just moving around the viewport in shader mode with only a few primitives. This isn't a complicated scene at all. It also either crashes when I try to render or just does nothing OR resorts to using CPU and spikes to 100% immediately turning my room into an oven and risking crashing again.

OpenGL/GPU seems to be supported in rendering and denoise UNTIL I go to preferences to double check, then it's only visible under CUDA, but nothing is recognized in OpenGL or optix
[image]

**What I've tried so far from what I could find online:**

- making sure the studio driver was what was installed from NVIDIA, clean install
- benchmark test to make sure nothing else was running poorly I was missing
- downloaded 2.93 blender but the most recent update to make sure it wasn't a bug that got fixed already
- tried with blender 3.0 (all the way through to the current 3.5 version that's on the front page of the site, as well as through Steam)
- made sure I have enough RAM, wattage, and my gpu was supported
- made sure everything was on and set to compatible in NVIDIA 3d settings
- tried that again but with high performance instead

even with nothing else running blender doesn't want to actually use my gpu and crashes every few minutes. It doesn't matter which version, and not other gpu heavy programs are having issues.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Blender? 2.93 is from 2021, pretty sure back then there were no RTX 4000 cards so I'm not surprised those aren't well supported. Also in you image it shows Open**CL** not Open**GL**, which is a computing API for AMD cards not supported on NVidia. as L0Lock mentions below.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yeah I made a typo. I was using 2.93 and other older versions that are stable to troubleshoot and make the point that this affects old and new versions of Blender: even if CPU is unchecked it doesn't seem to utilize GPU at all and skips over to just using CPU regardless of version

Comment: You should use the current version(3.5.1 now) unless you have a good reason not to. If you want to use the GPU for rendering, you should set OptiX for RTX 4070 TI card. Make sure latest drivers are installed for your GPU. Try regular drivers, whatever they are called, not the "Studio" ones. You should not touch any driver settings. Defaults should work fine, no need to "optimize" anything. If you have RTX card and it's not showing under render devices when you select OptiX, it probably means, there is something wrong with the driver, you could try different driver versions.

Comment: So did you enable your GPU in either CUDA or OptiX, and left either of them enabled in your preferences? Is your scene small enough to fit in your GPU to begin with?

Comment: @L0Lock yes my scene was just a few primitives with basic shaders as a test. Originally since I'm new to blender and was following a tutorial I thought this was something to do with OptiX or similar but had issues with any option, even CUDA (openCL was what was used in the tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an update for anyone reading this in the future with the same issue: it turned out to be an SSD/GPU issue that just happened to only really show when using blender and trying to render. Originally thought from a tutorial that it was the method of rendering I was using but turned out to be a few problems with windows update/nvidia driver interference/ssd issue.

- check event logger and fix all critical, most were PFN errors.
- I went through the steps to troubleshoot that and initially ran into more issues than just blender (so the late update), but eventually this is what fixed all of it including blender render issues.
- using DDU to clean reinstall NVIDIA drivers worked better than Revo clean uninstall and reinstall
- then in command line running chkdsk and then scan and check offline (requires reboot) is what ultimately worked

Had to dig deep online to find any helpful answers but it seems to be an issue that's caused by a conflict between NVIDIA driver updates + Windows update + new version of blender basically all not quite aligned, and chkdsk likely worked for me from file conflicts from what I could tell online.

Hopefully anyone else who has this issue this works for them and it's not such a nightmare to troubleshoot.

Comment: glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia GPUs will use either CUDA or OptiX. Any "RTX" model will benefit from OptiX.

OpenCL was for AMD and Intel GPUs and was deprecated in favor of HIP and oneAPI back in 2021 for Blender 3.0.

[GPU Rendering — Blender Manual v2.93](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

[GPU Rendering — Blender Manual v3.5](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware)

Comment: yes but the point is that on old stable version of blender and on the newer versions my GPU isn't being used even where it *is* recognized and even when CPU is unchecked. Blender seems to override for some reason and just not use GPU at all regarldess of option.